# 401 error on CWS Payment Flow

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My Google Chrome Extension (Annotate for Chrome) has successfully received payments.

I have updated the app recently but not the payment flow.

Now when a user initiates a payment the Google modal pops up (that displays the Google payment - from Buy.js) the spinner just runs endlessly and console shows a 401 error.

I double-checked manifest and in-app purchase SKU etc and don't see any differences from previous versions that worked. My check for current license is working fine - which tells me my app is being recognized by the Google Web Store and returning data on specific users license status...

Any thoughts on what could cause this? Many thanks.

(I submitted a ticket to CWS support - nothing yet). Probably something stupid but I don't know how to debug. Or epic fail on Google's part.

Comment: This is a problem with Chrome Web Store, not my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this issue has been fixed and purchase flows should be working as expected now. Details over here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/bxoptYk8--Y/Mh_qJp4gDQAJ

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the Chrome Web Store.

I tried to purchase another Extension (https://www.twinword.com/blog/how-to-quickly-monetize-your-chrome-browser/) that uses in-app purchases and saw the exact same problem.

So Google's Web Store purchasing process has been broken for a week+ and no one at Google cares. Maybe they should get out of the payments business and require developers use 3rd party solutions. Utterly disgusting on Google's part. I'd like my 6 hours of troubleshooting back...

Comment: CWS has confirmed that this issue is resolved and my Extension is again able to flow through to payment. For the record:)